# Bell State 11 not working for parity curve

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, bell-experiment

I am currently writing a script to automate the creation of parity curves for a 2 qubit bell state and then calculate fidelity and proving entanglement from that (inspired by [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07080) paper). It was going really well. I am able to run simulations perfectly for states 00 and its complement state 10 (getting fidelity values on ibmqx4 of roughly 0.7). Although, it then starts to get weird running states 11 and its complement 01. Although I haven't run state 01 on the real machine yet, the simulation of it runs perfectly. State 11 however, doesn't. As far as I understand 11 and 01 should output similar results. Here's a sample of my 01 states results.

```
10,471
11,40 
00,43
01,440
10,490
11,51
00,54
```

As you can see, a variety of states come out, allowing me to calculate parity. Running exactly the same code with state 11 instead gives

```
10,471
01,498
10,526
01,528
10,496
01,514
10,510
```

which, obviously looks a lot more like a generic bell state with no rotation. The code used to set up the circuit and rotation for simulation is shown below. The math for theta, lam and phi for states 00 and 10 are taken from the paper mentioned above (on the second column of text on page 2). Math for states 11 and 01 are not on the paper but was worked out by my supervisor.

```
# Set range for rotation 
phi_range = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 128)

for phi_value in phi_range:
    # inside the loop because putting it outside breaks it and makes it run 
    # really really slow
    qr = QuantumRegister(2, name='qr')
    cr = ClassicalRegister(2, name='cr')
    bell = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr, name='bell')

    # Set the details of the rotation
    if startingState == '00' or startingState == '10':
        theta = np.pi/2
        lam = -phi_value - np.pi/2

    elif startingState == '01' or startingState == '11':
        theta = phi_value
        lam = 0 - np.pi/2
    else:
        raise ValueError('Setting rotation problems')

    phi = -lam

    # initializing the starting state of the circuit (done separately to 
    # above for clarity)
    if startingState == '01':
        bell.x(qr[1])
    elif startingState == '10':
        bell.x(qr[0])
    elif startingState == '11':
        bell.x(range(2))

    # this is the bell state code itself
    bell.h(qr[0])
    bell.cx(qr[0], qr[1])

    bell.barrier()
    bell.u3(theta, lam, phi, qr)
    bell.barrier()

    bell.measure(qr[0], cr[0])
    bell.measure(qr[1], cr[1])
```

I have checked that this creates the correct circuit several times over, and again, it works for all states except 11. Can anyone work out why?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Could you explain what `phi` is in your program?

Comment: @JamesWootton Thanks for the reply. The u3 gate needs 4 arguments, as far as I could work out they are rotations around the x, y and z axis respectively plus the 4th argument being the quantum register. If that is correct (which I'm not 100% sure about), that would mean `phi` is rotation around the z axis. [This](https://qiskit.org/documentation/autodoc/qiskit.extensions.standard.u3.html?highlight=u3#module-qiskit.extensions.standard.u3) is the qiskit documentation of the u3 gate. The matrix equation for the gate is shown in the paper linked at the top.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mean `phi_value`. The thing you loop over

Comment: @JamesWootton No worries, `phi_value` loops through `phi_range`, which is just a array of (in this case 128) numbers between 0 and pi. It later allows me to create a nice evenly spaced plot of the parity at the corresponding `phi_value`.